# Cacti graph not showing properly

Tags: graph, monitoring, rrdtool, rrd, cacti

Hoping to reach all of you Cacti experts right there. I have tried posting the same issue on the Cacti forums website, but after nearly a week had no answer. Hoping to have more luck here.

I'm pretty new to Cacti, and in the past days I've worked my way through to installation, configuration, etc.

I am now at a stage where I need to hook up the system I need to monitor (called Diffusion) into cacti. Diffusion is a java-based push engine, and my aim is to graph specific MBeans the server exposes.

I have created Perl scripts that give me the info I need in a correct fashion, and built a graph template to display data from 4 data sources pertaining a threadpool.

As of now the values are fixed, hence the outcome is always 0, 3, 8 and 10 (4 data sources, dumping on 4 rrds).

For some reason, though the only line I can see is the one returning 0, and the graph is sized between 0 and 1, wehreas I'd expect to see the other lines as well and the graph being sized between 0 and some value above 10.

[image]

Just to make it clear, logs (DEBUG level) do not show any warning, data gathering seems to work well, and I have no "complain" from cacti when creating sources, templates, etc.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you post a copy of your graph and data source debug to be reviewed?  Cacti should let you see the rrdgraph, rrdcreate, and rrdupdate commands it is generating.

Comment: I managed to fix the issue by changing the graph type to GAUGE.
Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a few attempts with changing a variety of parameters, I managed to solve the issue by simply changing the graph type to GAUGE.

Seems to wrk pretty well now.